# How come when I have int answer = in.nextInt(); in line 8 nothing appears, but when I put it in line 13 something appears?

Tags: java

*EDIT*

So I didn't realize that the program was running, it was just blank, because java reads down, the system was waiting for me to input the answer before I saw the answer. Thank you @wdc for your help.

*Original*

I'm currently practicing java, I came into a problem that I solved, but I don't understand why, how come the program runs when I have it like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number1 = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() % 10);
        int number2 = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() / 10 % 10);



        System.out.print("What is " +  number1 + " + " + number2 + "?");

        int answer = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println(number1 + " + " + number2 + " = " + answer + " is " + (number1 + number2 == answer));


    }

}
```

But doesn't work when I have it like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            int number1 = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() % 10);
            int number2 = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() / 10 % 10);
            int answer = in.nextInt();



            System.out.print("What is " +  number1 + " + " + number2 + "?");


            System.out.println(number1 + " + " + number2 + " = " + answer + " is " + (number1 + number2 == answer));


        }

    }
```

I want to know so I can avoid this problem in the future.

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work`?

Comment: And what is the thing that is appearing?

Comment: The program will stop to wait for user input at line  **int answer = in.nextInt()**; so in second example "What is.." will only be printed after user inserts number.

Comment: Both programs run. Maybe explain what you're expecting to happen.... Start by adding print statements between every single line

Comment: What do *you* think `in.nextInt()` does, and why do you think so?

Comment: @tkausl I mean nothing appears

Comment: in.nextInt() is where the user inputs the data, I just thought that because I have ' == answer ' that the program would ask the user to enter it data, I didn't know why it had to be placed in a certain place

Comment: "Nothing appears" is far different from "doesn't work". The latter simply means that it doesn't do what you expected. Which you'll need to clarify. Moving lines of code around usually means execution behavior changes

Comment: @cricket_007 I expect the program to run and ask the user the question "What is # + # ?" Then the user enters. Because I thought that if I put the definition where int number 1 and int number 2 is, I could still get the user to input their answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly, you are not sure why is the output different in this two cases?

Note that java executes the statements in the order as they appear in the code. So,

When you put `int answer = in.nextInt();` before the `System.out.print("What is " +  number1 + " + " + number2 + "?");` your program is waiting for user input and you don't see anything printed on the screen. If you enter something in the console and press enter, the program will continue it's execution and you would see the rest of the output.

But if you move `int answer = in.nextInt();` after the print statement the first print statement will be executed and you would see some output in the console.

Comment: You ma add the hint that java executes the statements in a method in order of appearance. This might be helpful for a newbie...

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. I figured out why, so because the program reads down, the reason why it was blank wasn't that nothing was happening, it was that it was waiting for me to input an answer before seeing the question. So either way, the program runs just fine. Thank you for helping me understand!

Comment: Thank you @TimothyTruckle! Yeah, I realized that.

Answer (score 0):

Well saying it doesn't work its not really correct, because it does.
The problem is in the seconde snippet you have the blocking method  "in.nextInt()", before the console print of the question, so you need to put he answer and only after you have the question.

Comment: Thank you @Ocirederf94! I realized that.